# Find all solutions to $2x \equiv p \mod 3p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

> Find all solutions to $2x \equiv p \pmod {3p}$. $p$ is prime, and $p > 3$.

I found that this is equal to $2x = p(3k+ 1)$ for some $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Since $k$ can't be even, then we have $2x = \{4p, 10p, 16p, 22p\}$ so the solution set is $x = \{(2+3s)p\}$, for some $s \in \Bbb{N}$.

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Also is $p$ prime?

Comment: Find all solutions to$ 2x≡p \mod 3p.$ $p$ is prime

Comment: $k$ _can_ be even, but then since $(3k+1)$ is odd you need $p=2$.

Comment: @Joffan I forgot to add that $p > 3$. I apologize.

Comment: @DonLarynx It would be helpful to know what you're looking for. Why are you posting this? (That's what AlexR is asking with "What is the question?")

Comment: @Théophile I'm worried I got a low grade on my final and this was one of the questions.

Comment: @DonLarynx I see. It would be helpful to explain that in the body of your question.

Comment: The solution is unnecessarily complex - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your solution is perfectly right, i.e., $x = p(3s+2)$, where $s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\,p\,$ is any odd integer then $\,{\rm mod}\ 3p\!:\,\ 2x\equiv p\equiv -2p\iff x\equiv -p\equiv 2p$

Comment: You added an extra step there. You could've done it this way: $2x\equiv p\equiv 4p\iff x\equiv 2p$.

Comment: @user31415 They're equivalent. The reason I did it that way is that generally it is more effiicient to work with least magnitude reps (so we would be done with $\,x\equiv -p)\ $ But I added $\,-p\equiv 2p\,$ for clarity.

Comment: what do you mean by 'reps'?

Comment: The chosen complete system of representatives for the congruence classes (remainders) mod $\,m,\,$ e.g. modulo $\,n=5\,$ we can use $\,0,1,2,3,4\,$ or $\,-2,-1,0,1,2\,$ (least magnitude).